# Database for Weapons?

Tags: c#, xml, xna, inventory

I'm creating a simple RPG game and currently I am working on weapon objects.
I currently have a W_Sword.cs class that has all the properties for any sword type weapons I want to create. For my inventory system I am simply going to have an array that stores integers and each number will represent the ID of an item.

My question is, if I have multiple classes for all types of items (consumables, swords, axes, shields etc.) how should I store all this in like a database for easy access?
So if I want to draw a specific weapon I can just call it from a database and create it as an object (on-screen, in the inventory etc.) I'm thinking an XML might be the way to go, but I'm not sure how to get the data from an XML file into my XNA code to create objects etc. from specific items in the XML.

Please let me know if I should elaborate further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XML is a good way to do this. It will allow for the easy addition of new items by yourself or even the end user.

Are the classes derived from a base class? My thinking is that, if you have a base class Item that consumables, swords, axes, shields, etc inherit from, you could try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<XnaContent>
  <Asset Type="Generic.List<MyDataTypes.Item>">
    <Item>
      <Name>Wooden Sword</Name>
      <Properties>10 10 10 10</Properties>
      <TextureName>WoodenSword</TextureName>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <Name>Wooden Shield</Name>
      <Properties>10 10 10 10</Properties>
      <TextureName>WoodenShield</TextureName>
    </Item>
  </Asset>
</XnaContent>
```

Then in your code:

```
// Load items into content
//http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff604980.aspx
List<Item> listOfItems = Content.Load<List<Item>>("xmlFileName");

foreach (Item item in listOfItems)
{
    myItemTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>(item.TextureName);
    ...
}
```

This is a general overview. I'm not currently at a computer with Visual Studio so I doubt the above is syntactically correct. If you wish for further help I can assist later today.

Comment: Ah I see, so loading from XML files is this easy? I've been looking for a straightforward tutorial on loading properties from an XML file as simple as this for a while.. Is there any chance I could message you privately somewhere? I know this site doesn't have a PM system.

Comment: I'm glad I could help! It would be best if we continued to communicate on this site so other users can learn. What further questions do you have?

Comment: Oh yeah good idea.
I'm wondering why you've set the Asset Type in the XML as "Generic.List<MyDataTypes.Item>", I know these are placeholder names but could you elaborate on what they represent? :)

Comment: Yes, the Type attribute specifies the corresponding namespace and class of the matching data type. This is required IF you want to include the .xml file in your Content. Right-click on your Content project in Visual Studio, Add > New Item and create an XML file; the generated file includes the Type attribute. You don’t have to include this if you would prefer to load XML via LINQ rather than the content pipeline. A good example of this can be found at http://machxgames.com/blog/?p=21. The user has a simple XML structure, LINQ can then be used to populate the list of items at runtime.

Comment: Alright so do I still have to create objects for each item I have in my code? I want to do this easily and space saving for when I have heaps of items, I just want to be able to call the object of them from 1 place.

Comment: You could either: 1) Populate a List containing one instance of every kind of item on startup. This will ensure the entire XML loading is complete at the start, but you could potentially be loading items that aren’t used. 2) Load the required items only when needed. This allows for quicker startup and ensures only required items are loaded into memory, thus easy and space saving.

Comment: Okay so:
Items in XML, then 
Load Items from XML as an object when needed??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54267/discussion-between-user3256944-and-user3451948).

Answer (score 0):

You could use an Object Database which can save and retrieve objects for you. For example  [NDatabase](http://ndatabase.codeplex.com/) And here is a small tutorial on [How to use it](http://ndatabase.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=1-minute-tutorial&referringTitle=quickstart-guide)